# Suddenly getting LDAP Referrals

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have two domains, a production and development.  My development domain has suddenly started giving the error `DirectoryServicesCOMException: A referral was returned from the server.`

This has only started happening today.  I validated it was working yesterday.  No changes have been identified with domain controllers or my application.

When my development server performs an LDAP search of a production user profile.  I'm using some fairly standard LDAP query code:

```
private IUserDetails queryUserBySID(string sid)
{
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(domainLdap); // "DC=production,DC=local"
    
    var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
    ds.Filter = $"(&(objectCategory=User)(objectClass=person)(objectSid={sid}))";
    
    var result = ds.FindOne(); // <-- referral error
    //...
}
```

However, this works (Even when using IIS AppPool credentials):

```
PS C:\> Get-ADUser -Server productiondc -Identity testuser
```

I validated both domains trust each other.  What could have changed on either of my domains to cause this?

#### Edit 1

The issue resolved itself for 1-2 days and then appeared again.

Checking the `ExtendedErrorMessage` gives

```
0000202B: RefErr: DSID-03100835, data 0, 1 access points
    ref 1: 'production.local'
```

A quick google shows to run `dcdiag`

#### Edit 2

I believe this to be a pertinent error with `dcdiag`:

```
An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC0000010

            Time Generated: 02/22/2022   22:22:22

            Event String:

            While processing a TGS request for the target server <user>/SERVER, the account DevMachine$@DEVELOPMENT.LOCAL did not have a suitable key for generating a Kerberos ticket (the missing key has an ID of 8). The requested etypes were 18  17. The accounts available etypes were 18  17  23  -133  -128  24  -135. Changing or resetting the password of PRODUCTION.LOCAL will generate a proper key.
```

Comment: Now I'm suspecting a windows update issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/699968/anyone-else-have-a-problem-with-net-function-getal.html (KB5009557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A referral means "I don't have the information you want, but I know where you can get it." So it's a mismatch between the server you're connecting to and where the data is. I can't tell you what changed, but I can tell you how to get more information about it.

After the exception is thrown, call [`de.Options.GetCurrentServerName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentryconfiguration.getcurrentservername) to see which server the search was performed on.

Then check the [`ExtendedErrorMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryservicescomexception.extendederrormessage) property of the exception and see if it tells you which server it is referring you to.

To get around the exception and automatically follow the referral, you can use the [`ReferralChasing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.referralchasing) property of the `DirectorySearcher`:

```
ds.ReferralChasing =  ReferralChasingOption.All;
```

Comment: The issue fixed itself overnight (no known domain changes) before I had a chance to check the `ExtendedErrorMessage`.  However, I did test `ReferralChasingOption.All` and it failed with the same error.

Comment: The issue is happening again, I was able to capture `ExtendedErrorMessage` and add that to my original post.

Comment: So that is telling you that you need to connect to `production.local`. Were you able to check `de.Options.GetCurrentServerName()` and see which server it is connecting to?

Comment: The `de.Options` object is empty.  Regardless, it looks like the issue was related to kerberos encryption types configured between `production.local` (AES128_HMAC_SHA1, AES256_HMAC_SHA1, Future encryption types).  `GPO -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Network security: Configure encryption types allowed for Kerberos`  After applying fresh GPO to synchronize that GPO—consequently Kerberos, queries started working again.

Comment: I expect it to connect to `development.local` or follow the referral, we are not explicitly connecting to `production.local` because we are performing anonymous queries from generic accounts (such as `development.local\webserver$`)